# javafx Tableview not showing data from database

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview

My table view is not able to show data in it. It is showing resultset data in console but unable to show in tableview javafx. Please help.

Class RoomDetails

```
package application;

public class RoomDetails<object> {

    rmlist rmList = new rmlist();
    getroom getRoom = new getroom();

    @FXML
    private Button btnRoom_add;
    @FXML
    private Button btnRoom_update;
    @FXML
    private Button btnRoom_del;
    @FXML
    private TableView<ListRoom> tblroomdetails;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<object, Object> tblroomno;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<object, Object> tblroomtype; 
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<object, Object> tblac;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<object, Object> tbltariff;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<object, Object> tblstatus;
    @FXML
    private Label lblRoomdetails;


    Dbconnection dbcon = new Dbconnection();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;

    @FXML 
    public void btnRoom_addonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader fXMLLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fXMLLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/AddRoom.fxml"));
        try{

    fXMLLoader.load();
            Parent parent = fXMLLoader.getRoot();
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            scene.setFill(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            AddRoom addRoom = fXMLLoader.getController();
            addRoom.lbl_Add_Room.setText("ADD Room");
             Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            stage.show();

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    public void viewDetails() {
        tblroomdetails.setItems(rmList.roomlist);
        getRoom.rmview(rmList);
        tblroomno.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roomno"));
        tblroomtype.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rmtype"));
        tblac.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("acstat"));
        tbltariff.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rmtariff"));
        tblstatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rmstatus"));

}       
}
```

Class getroom

```
package application;  

public class getroom {


    Dbconnection dbcon = new Dbconnection();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;

    public void rmview(rmlist rmList) {
        con = dbcon.geConnection();
        try{
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from room");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs);
            while (rs.next()){
                rmList.roomno = rs.getString(1);
                rmList.rmtype = rs.getString(2);
                rmList.acstat = rs.getString(3);
                rmList.rmtariff = rs.getString(4);
                rmList.rmstatus = rs.getString(5);
                }
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
                con.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    }
```

Class ListRoom

```
package application;

public class ListRoom {

    public String roomno;
    public String rmtype;
    public String acstat;
    public String rmtariff;
    public String rmstatus;
    public ListRoom(String roomno, String rmtype, String acstat, String rmtariff, String rmstatus) {
        super();
        this.roomno = roomno;
        this.rmtype = rmtype;
        this.acstat = acstat;
        this.rmtariff = rmtariff;
        this.rmstatus = rmstatus;
    }
    public String getRoomno() {
        return roomno;
    }
    public void setRoomno(String roomno) {
        this.roomno = roomno;
    }
    public String getRmtype() {
        return rmtype;
    }
    public void setRmtype(String rmtype) {
        this.rmtype = rmtype;
    }
    public String getAcstat() {
        return acstat;
    }
    public void setAcstat(String acstat) {
        this.acstat = acstat;
    }
    public String getRmtariff() {
        return rmtariff;
    }
    public void setRmtariff(String rmtariff) {
        this.rmtariff = rmtariff;
    }
    public String getRmstatus() {
        return rmstatus;
    }
    public void setRmstatus(String rmstatus) {
        this.rmstatus = rmstatus;
    }


}
```

Class rmlist

```
package application;

public class rmlist {

    public String roomno;
    public String rmtype;
    public String acstat;
    public String rmtariff;
    public String rmstatus;
public ObservableList<ListRoom> roomlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

}
```

class DBConnection

```
package application;

class DBconnection{
        public Connection con;
         String username = "root";
         String password = "123456";
         String driverclass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
         String db_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
         String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false";

         public Connection mkDataBase() throws SQLException{
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);

                } catch (Exception e){

                }
                return con;
            }

            public Connection geConnection(){

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url+"hotel"+unicode, username, password);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Too Many Connection");
                }

                return con;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what is `Dbconnection`?

Comment: @James_D This could be the missing class definition :))

Comment: I will never understand why people who want help can't take the time to make sure their question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getRoom.rmview` method you fill assign the fields of the `rmview` instance again and again, but you never modify the `roomlist` of `rmview` is never modified; it remains empty. Since you use `roomlist` in the `TableView`, there is no data to show.

You should instead add a new element for every row the database query returns:

```
// remove data previously in the list
rmList.roomlist.clear();

while (rs.next()){
    rmList.roomlist.add(new ListRoom(rs.getString(1),
                                     rs.getString(2),
                                     rs.getString(3),
                                     rs.getString(4),
                                     rs.getString(5)));
}
```

---

Furthermore I recommend adhering to [the naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html). Especially the part about abreviations since this makes your code hard to read for others. Furthermore `object` is a bad choice as name for a type parameter. It leads to confusion and usually single uppercase letters are used for type parameters.

Also the purpose of the `rmlist` class is unclear. It contains the same fields as `ListRoom`, but also contains a list where you want the data to actually be stored. Why do you need those fields? Do you need `rmlist` at all or could it just be replaced with `ObservableList<ListRoom>`?

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem. From next time onwards will take care of naming.