# javafx tableview not able to fetch data while initializing

Tags: mysql, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to populate tableview at the time of loading. Please forgive if there is any mistake.

```
public class users {

    public String username;
    public String FullName;
    public String password;
    public String phone;
    public String email;
    public String doj;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String address;


    public ObservableList <ListEmply> emplylst = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

}
```

---

```
public class UserDetail {

    @FXML
    private ObservableList <ListEmply> emplylst;
    @FXML
    private TableView <ListEmply> tbl_employeeview;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Object, Object> employeename;

    users User = new users();


    Dbconnection dbcon = new Dbconnection();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;



    public void showDetails(users User){
        con = dbcon.geConnection();
        try{
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select room_no from room");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
        User.emplylst.add(new ListEmply(
                rs.getString(1)
                ));

                }
        System.out.println(rs);
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    public void usrdetails(){
        tbl_employeeview.setItems(emplylst);
        showDetails(User);
        employeename.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("employeename"));
        System.out.println(rs);
    }


    public void Initializable(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

        usrdetails();
    }   
}
```

ListEmply Class

```
public class ListEmply {

    public String employeename;
    public ListEmply(String employeename) {
        super();
        this.employeename = employeename;
    }
    public String getEmployeename() {
        return employeename;
    }
    }
    public void setEmployeename(String employeename) {
        this.employeename = employeename;
    }
}
```

Comment: As was suggested to you in an [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398050/javafx-tableview-not-showing-data-from-database), you should follow [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers), the controller method that is called to initialize the controller is called `initialize(...)`, not `Initializable(...)`:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

    usrdetails();
}
```

As noted by @fabian in the comments, since you are not implementing the (legacy) interface `Initializable` and not using the parameters, you can omit the parameters from the method definition:

```
public void initialize(){

    usrdetails();
}
```

Comment: True, and I agree that is preferable. Added to answer.

Comment: I'm getting error at  this line tbl_employeeview.setItems(emplylst);

Comment: Then you're probably doing something wrong there. Did you initialize `emplylst` anywhere? You can't really expect anyone on this forum to fix every single one of your (probably many) errors one by one: I answered the question you posted as to why the initialization wasn't happening, but I can't allow the question to degenerate into fixing all your typos one at a time. Read the error message and fix the problem accordingly.